# Ajax reports back a '1' for IE

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, internet-explorer

I'm trying to create a functional page for parents who refuse to download anything except IE on to their machine(s). Anyhow, its a list and I just wanted some AJAX togglable buttons that were backed up by a database.

I'm not sure what's up but the below gets called and received fine in both firefox & chrome. No matter what I do in IE (any version) I can't get it to work. The onreadystatechange function always receives and reports "1" instead of "off" or "on" as it should. This originally threw me because I was just trying to send 1's and 0's.

Anyhow, IE doesn't actually commit any of the values, so I imagine there's something wrong with the attempt to get to the PHP page and receive a response. Sorry for being a n00b, but what can cause this?

Unfortunately, the web page has some sensitive info I don't want people to see, so sensored code below:

JAVASCRIPT FUNCTION:

```
function toggleResponded(i) {
    var respondedHttp;  
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        respondedHttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }   else    {// code for IE6, IE5
        respondedHttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    alert("toggling responded for element: " + i);

    respondedHttp.onreadystatechange = function() {         
        if(respondedHttp.readyState==4 && respondedHttp.status==200) {
            var state = respondedHttp.responseText;
            alert("Recieved: " + state);
            if(state == "off") {
                document.getElementById("respond"+i).className = "inLineOff";
                document.getElementById("respond"+i).innerHTML = "No Response Yet";
                document.getElementById("attend"+i).style.display="none";
                document.getElementById("quantityCell"+i).style.display="none";
            } else if(state == "on") {
                document.getElementById("respond"+i).className = "inLineOn";
                document.getElementById("respond"+i).innerHTML = "Responded";
                document.getElementById("attend"+i).style.display="inline";
                if(document.getElementById("attend"+i).innerHTML == "Attending") {
                    document.getElementById("quantityCell"+i).style.display="table-cell";
                }
            } else {
                alert("error: " + state);
            }
        }
    }

    var name = peeps.people[i];

    alert("toggling for: " + name); 
    alert("toggling as: " + encodeURIComponent(name));

    var ops = "./quer.php?";    
    ops += "op=toggleResponded";
    ops += "&name=" + encodeURIComponent(name);

    alert("going to: " + ops);

    respondedHttp.open("GET", ops, true);
    respondedHttp.send();
}
```

PHP:

```
if(isset($_GET["op"])) {
    switch($_GET["op"]) {
        case "toggleResponded":
            $name = mysql_real_escape_string(rawurldecode($_GET["name"]));
            $database->executeStatement("SELECT * FROM table WHERE nameField='$name'");
            $info = $database->nextResult();
            $nval = 0;
            if($info["Responded"] == 0) {
                $nval = 1;
            }
            $database->executeStatement("UPDATE table SET field='$nval' WHERE nameField='$name'");
            if($nval == 1) {
                echo "on";
            } else {
                echo "off";
            }           
        break;
```

Comment: Can you post what you are getting as output on the alerts.

Comment: I'm getting the appropriate adresses & escapes (same exactly as chrome outputs), but instead of getting "on" or "off" back I get "error: 1" for that last output, and alert("Recieved: " + state); gives "Recieved: 1"

Comment: Kirk, your code seems fine, do yo know how to swap to using POST instead of get?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IE caches ajax aggressively, and since you were originally returning 1s and 0s it is probably just cached data. Add the current date to the URL you're requesting.

```
var d = new Date();
ops = ops + '&nocache=' + d.getTime();
```

Comment: IE is actually following the W3C spec here, where it says that GET requests are cachable.

Comment: @danp Wasn't implying it was wrong in doing so, just saying that it does indeed do it.

Comment: yep - I would go down this route clientside if I couldn't modify the server code, otherwise I'd just swap cleanly to using posts.

Comment: I will try this now. EDIT: Success! | I don't care if that's a standard, that is really really annoying. Someone needs to re-write that standard.

Answer (score 0):

Use POST instead of GET and everything will be fine. IE caches GETs, there's nothing mystical happening.

Comment: This seems to be the technically correct way of doing it. On future projects I'll do it this way, but its not worth redoing any of my code right now to simply have a standards correct implementation since this is a one-off and is fully functional now. Thanks anyways.